# Can Open Layers display Vector Tiles delivered as Protocol Buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers, openlayers-3

Can the tileUrlFunction in ol.source.TileVector return a protocol buffer or does it have to be (geo | topo)json?

Comment: This is being worked on currently.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `tileUrlFunction` is only responsible to return an URL where ol3 can download the vector tile in the specified format. The list of supported formats (not just JSON) can be found in the [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.html). Currently, these are:

- EsriJSON
- GeoJSON
- GML
- GML2
- GML3
- GPX
- IGC
- JSONFeature
- KML
- OSMXML
- Polyline
- TextFeature
- TopoJSON
- WFS
- WKT
- WMSCapabilities
- XMLFeature

While there is no built in support for protocol buffers, you can pass a `tileLoadFunction` to your [`ol.source.TileVector`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.TileVector.html) instead of specifying a built in format. That function will be called with the URL of a tile, and is responsible for loading the features (in this case, parse the buffers and create ol3 features).